# Data-bind keypress event does not work on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, kendo-ui

So I ran into this issue recently.

The goal is use enter key to open selected line and also be able to go up and down using arrows. In order to open selected div , I need to pass the name of selected to the function that launches it. So it is important to detect targeted element.

[image]

Project uses Knockout js so I have code like this:

```
<div class="prod-item k-widget" id="#:Id#" data-bind=" events:  {  click: prodItem_onClick, dblclick: btnStartPopup_onClick,}">
```

Which works fine and indeed fires prodItem_onClick and btnStartPopup_onClick.

Now I need an event handler that catches the keypress. So I go ahead and do the same thing  and add another event handler.

```
<div class="prod-item k-widget" id="#:Id#" data-bind=" events:{keyup: moveList, click: prodItem_onClick, dblclick: btnStartPopup_onClick,}">
```

Now weird thing starts to happen. First of all it does not fire the moveList function. I tried 'a' tag and it did not work either. However it does work fine on input event. But I need it to work on a div that has two lines and is not an input type.

I also tried to capture keypress events with jQuery as well, the issue here is I can not get the targeted element. I get the html of whole container div.

Any ideas how to get around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the syntax error

sample event binding :

`<div data-bind="event: { mouseover: enableDetails, mouseout:disableDetails }"> Mouse over me
</div>`

In your case

```
<div class="prod-item k-widget" id="#:Id#" data-bind="event:{keyup: moveList},click: prodItem_onClick, dblclick: btnStartPopup_onClick">
```

Comment: Good catch. I fixed it. But that is not the case. I miss typed

Comment: @NamigIsmayilov you still have syntax error, its "event" not "events". Also keep "click" out side of event block.